# Ansi C runtime performance global vs. local variables

Tags: c, performance, variables

I'm thinking about run time performance depending on the definition of a local variable. Which variant may be executed faster or is there no difference?

Variant 1:

```
extern uint8 GlobalArray[10];
void myFunc(void)
{
  int i;
  uint8_t* pNumber;
  for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
    pNumber = &(globalArray[i]);
    // Do anything with pNumber
  }
}
```

Variant 2:

```
extern uint8 GlobalArray[10];
void myFunc(void)
{
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
    uint8_t* pNumber = &(globalArray[i]);
    // Do anything with pNumber
  }
}
```

Comment: Measure it? Then you have results for your platform/compiler

Comment: a) you aren't making a global-related change here (`pNumber` is local both times, just in different places); b) *why* do you think this might affect performance?

Comment: As neither of those will even compile, I somewhat doubt there will be any difference whatsoever. Even fixing the plethora of errors, depending on usage, after optimization I doubt `pNumber` even exists as a concrete variable in the final asm code in *either* case.

Comment: I would *really* be surprised if a compiler created code that adds `pNumber` on the stackframe and removes it again for each iteration of the loop. Therefore no difference expected

Comment: Most compilers probably generate exactly the same code for both variants. Demonstration: https://www.godbolt.org/z/-jRo--

Comment: You could use the optimizer and the "generate assembly" option on your compiler and see what the generated assembly is.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between 1) and 2), because there is no relation between when a variable is declared in the source and when it is put the stack/in a register in the real application.

It is good practice to reduce scope as much as possible, but that has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: The standard says: _" ... If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the
object is created each time."_. So I assume that it affects performance in a negligible way, because in 1, the local variable is created only once, while in 2, it is created in each iteration.

Comment: @machine_1 That's not the observable behavior, but merely a discription of how scope works. The compiler is free to "create" the new object at the same memory location as it had last time. Nothing in the C standard forces the compiler to allocate variables, except perhaps if the variable is `volatile` qualified.

Comment: So the compiler is free to make variant 2 the same as variant 1 under the hood? That is, to make it behave as if variant 1 was chosen?

Comment: @machine_1 Yes. See for example https://godbolt.org/z/h7FL2t. The machine code is identical.

Comment: The compiler can create any code that behaves "as if" it was exactly what you wrote in your C program. As stack usage is not defined in the standard, the compiler it is free to decide when to allocate memory.

Comment: That's exactly the point. From architecture point of view I want to make it as local as possible. But this code is executed in an embedded environment on a SoC thousands of times in a second. So even a small impact on runtime performance may have a huge impact on the system. I thought about the effort to create a new variable on stack. If it is only a few clocks, I guess the architecture point of view predominates.

Comment: @Christian Don't try to optimize before you have found a bottleneck - this goes for any system, embedded systems included. Your code doesn't need to be "as fast as possible", it needs to meet the real-time requirements. Nothing else matters. If a small impact of your execution speed has a huge impact on the system, your system design is broken by tight coupling. The average embedded system always has a background program which isn't particularly performance-critical.